# Creating Docker Swarm from Cloud in Azure failes

Tags: azure-container-service

Creating a Docker Swarm from docker cloud failes every time in creation.

Error Log docker Cloud:
https://gist.github.com/254813f30376c4ef1da20f320b29f815.git

Error Log Azure Portal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6N2U.png

Extended Error Log in Azure:
https://gist.github.com/c95bc0e24129c43341d874397609f550.git

Answer (score 0):

The error log indicates that you put an invalid SSH public key. It should be something like `ssh-rsa ...`